# Update log level in websphere cluster

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, levels

We use JDK logger on WAS6.1 and have a web page(JSP) to update the log level for a given package.
The request is sent to Servlet which gets the current set of loggers for the package and updates the new level to each of them.

But the war/ear is going to be deployed in cluster and now the question is, how do i ensure that the log levels are updated in all the nodes and not just the node to which the request was sent?

FYI, we have Spring, JDK logging, JEE1.4 in our application

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using JMX. Each WebSphere instance exposes an MBean of type [TraceService](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.wsfep.doc/web/mbeanDocs/TraceService.html) that allows to set the log levels. That MBean uses WebSphere specific conventions, but in the end it updates the log levels of the JDK loggers (java.util.logging).

You can either connect to each cluster member directly, or you can connect to the deployment manager and look up the relevant TraceService MBeans from there (the MBean server of the deployment manager actually provides a federated view that includes all MBeans registered in all servers in the cell).